Is CoComelon hyperstimulating and harmful for children?
I have a kid. He's enamored by CoComelon. The ability of CoComelon to captivate a child seems unique when compared to other shows. According to Newsweek

Many parents reported addictive behaviors in their children, followed by tantrums when they attempted to wean them off the cartoon. Others attributed speech delays, missed milestones and neurodevelopmental disorders, such as ADHD and autism, to CoComelon. Roseann Capanna-Hodge is an integrative and pediatric mental health expert and the founder of the Global Institute of Children's Mental Health. She said it is no coincidence that these claims began during the pandemic, when the amount of screen time increased dramatically among children. "Parents of young children were [suddenly] trapped at home and fell into the pattern of watching too much television," she told Newsweek.

She goes on to say,

Hodge agreed that CoComelon can be highly stimulating for young children due to the vivid colors and energetic music. "They can produce a dopamine release in the brain, similar to drugs," she said. "This can lead to boredom and poor behavioral and emotional regulation."

You can see another similar claims in Newsweek,

Jerrica Sannes, an expert in early childhood, development and education, claimed the show was not only overstimulating, it’s also likely to cause behavioral problems and attention disorders. “CoComelon is so hyper-stimulating that it acts as a drug, a stimulant. The brain receives a hit of dopamine from screen time, and it seems that the stronger the ‘drug’, the stronger the ‘hit’,” she told the publication.

I want to focus on the last part, which claims colors and music make CoComelon is hyperstimulating. Is there any research to substantiate that,

anything makes CoComelon "hyperstimulating"
and, more harmful to children than what preceded it such as Sesame Street, Captain Kangaroo, or other animated programs children have been growing up with for the past 60 years?


Is anyone arguing it is unique, as opposed to just at one example from one end of a spectrum of TV shows, which was lucky enough to have a viewing boost from lock downs?

The term the article uses is "hyperstimulating". But, I think that's semantic. Is Ebola a unique virus? Or is it a virus like all others but hyperdestructive. Anyway, I'll update it to use "hyperstimulating" and leave it to the answers to parse it further.

If you'd like, I can try to dig it up, but I did see an analysis where someone counted the camera change frequency in the average Cocomelon episode with them basically stating that it changed so rapidly as to create hyperstimulus in the child. It was, however, a YouTube video, so probably not all that scholarly.
